# phpMyAdmin not showing newly imported records in MyISAM table :(

Tags: phpmyadmin

I've been using phpMyAdmin - 2.10.1 and MyISAM tables for months with no problems. Today, I imported a .csv file with new records into one of my tables as per usual.

It said the import was successful, but when I browse to the end of my table, those new records do not appear. However, when I searched for one of the records in a query it showed up. What's going on here? And how do I fix it?

The last record that is showing up through the browse feature has a key of 13100 but, when I search for the first newly imported record it does appear in the query results and with a key of 13101.

The table is only 1.1 MiB. It was showing a little overhead, so I optimized it, hoping it would help this problem and it did not.  :(

Comment: Well, I never figured out what caused this issue, but after all else failed . . . I finally copied the table into an entirely new table and everything works as normal again. I wonder if tables can just 'go bad' or get corrupt or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow. Looking back at this old question: the reason they wouldn't show up at the end of the table was the records were being inserted into empty space elsewhere in the table. I had previously deleted records and that space was being filled up by the new import. So they records were there, just buried in the table, not at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a table first before importing the .csv file.
Get all the headings of the columns in there and make sure it's the same number as your document, then import into that table.